# PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo members are all 0

Tags: c, linux, alsa, portaudio

From the [PortAudio docs](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/api_overview.html):

> Stream Timing Information
>
> When using the callback I/O method your stream callback function
>   receives timing information via a pointer to a
>   PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo structure. This structure contains the
>   current time along with the estimated hardware capture and playback
>   time of the first sample of the input and output buffers. All times
>   are measured in seconds relative to a Stream-specific clock. The
>   current Stream clock time can be retrieved using Pa_GetStreamTime().

So `PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo::currentTime` somehow indicates the current time and `PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo::outputBufferDacTime` should indicate the output time of the first sample in the current buffer. I don't know why but, on Linux, these values are all zero for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Here's the code and the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "portaudio.h"

#define PI 3.14159265359
#define SRATE 44100
#define FREQ 440
#define DURATION 5000

int
audio_callback(
    const void* inbuf,
    void* outbuf,
    unsigned long bufsize,
    const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* time_info,
    PaStreamCallbackFlags status_flags,
    void* user_data)
{
    (void)inbuf;
    (void)status_flags;

    double* phase = (double*)user_data;
    float* out = (float*)outbuf;

    printf(
        "current time = %f; out time = %f\n",
        time_info->currentTime,
        time_info->outputBufferDacTime);

    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < bufsize; i++)
    {
        *phase += 2 * PI * FREQ / SRATE;
        out[i] = sin(*phase);
    }

    return 0;
}

int     
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    PaError pa_error;
    PaStream* stream = NULL;
    int error = 0;    
    double phase = 0;

    pa_error = Pa_Initialize();
    if (pa_error != paNoError)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    pa_error = Pa_OpenDefaultStream(
        &stream,
        0,
        1,
        paFloat32,
        SRATE,
        paFramesPerBufferUnspecified,
        &audio_callback,
        &phase);
    if (pa_error != paNoError)
    {
        error = 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    pa_error = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    if (pa_error != paNoError)
    {
        error = 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    Pa_Sleep(DURATION);

    pa_error = Pa_CloseStream(stream);
    if (pa_error != paNoError)
    {
        error = 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    printf("Done.\n");

exit:
    Pa_Terminate();

    if (pa_error != paNoError)
    {
        printf("PortAudio error: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(pa_error));
    }

    return error;
}
```

Output:

```
current time = 0.000000; out time = 0.000000
current time = 0.000000; out time = 0.000000
current time = 0.000000; out time = 0.000000
current time = 0.000000; out time = 0.000000
...
```

**Addendum**: This same piece of code seems to work fine with Visual Studio in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Your example compiles fine on my Mac and returns meaningful time information so the issue is not in your code.

You haven't said which audio backend you're using on Linux, but if you're using *ALSA* and *PulseAudio*, there've been problems getting time info with those (see [there](http://portaudio.music.columbia.narkive.com/cJ4dWvTd/getstreamtime-with-alsa-hostapi) for instance). In this specific case of *ALSA/PulseAudio*, *Pulse* is the one to blame and *PortAudio* has nothing to do with that.

If you're using a different audio backend, you might want to check the implementation of the `GetStreamTime()` function in the corresponding `src/hostapi/<your_backend>` *PortAudio* source folder.

---

As a side note, never make I/O operations in an audio callback in a real product. `printf` is a huge function which takes quite a lot of time to execute (from an audio callback point-of-view).

Comment: Is there any way to get the correct time info with ALSA backend?